# Form does not want to submit?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to submit my form to the console to see if it prints anything, but it's not working. Does anyone know what is going on?:

```
  return (
    <form className="form-add-friend" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label> Friend name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />

      <label> Image URL</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={image}
        onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
      />

      <Button>Add</Button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default FormAddFriend;
```

Comment: the code before: 

function FormAddFriend() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("https://i.pravatar.cc/48?u=499476");

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const id = crypto.randomUUID();
    const newFriend = {
      id,
      name,
      image,
      balance: 0,
    };
    console.log(newFriend);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Add `type = "submit"` on your button. Clicking on simple button does not trigger submit event. Once, you define the type of button as submit, form submit event will be triggered on clicking.

Another way of submitting form is to press 'Enter' inside your input field. This will also trigger submit event.

Comment: didn't work:( As my button component is inside of the form element and as the form has the onSubmit prop it should work by itself right?

Comment: Can you post your <Button> code? Is it a custom component?